# Chapter numbers in book class starting at 0, not increasing

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

I am working on making a template for a poetry book using the book class. However, I have noticed that there is a major issue that I encounter when adding chapters to the book. The chapter numbers are all listed as 'Chapter 0", even though there are multiple of them. I thought initially that it may because of a misplaced \mainmatter command, however it does not appear to be the case. Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4page]{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[numberpoems,clearpageafterpoem,useincipits]{poetrytex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setromanfont{Raleway}
\usepackage{rotating,lscape}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\stanzaskip}{0.75\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\poemauthorcenter}[1]{\nopagebreak{\footnotesize\textsc{#1}\par}}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\normalfont\itshape\LARGE}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-4em}
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}
    {Content\\\footnotesize\normalfont\itshape{/kənˈtɛnt/\\$^{1}$In a state of peaceful happiness \\$^{2}$The things that are held or included in something}}%

\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\\\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\vspace*{-5ex}}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Left side on Even pages; Right side on Odd pages
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf[lef,rof]{\thepage}%
}


\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
            \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    %\vspace*{1\p@}%
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\ptdedication}{Here is a \\Dedication}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{titlepage}

\makededication
\maketoc

\mainmatter
\chapter{Journey}
\lipsum
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}

\end{document}
```

edit: I have also attempted to use the `\setcounter` command, however whilst this changes the chapter number from 0 to 1, it relabels all of the chapters as this, so there is no increase in the chapter numbering.

Comment: please remove the \input so the example doesn't give `! LaTeX Error: File `titlepage.tex' not found.` it might be good to mention that you need to use xelatex with this code as it gives errors with lulatex or pdflatex

Answer (score 3):

One of your packages is disabling chapter numbering, presumably intentionally however the simplest change is to add `\refstepcounter` just before you use the counter, so

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
\refstepcounter{chapter}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    %\vspace*{1\p@}%
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}
```

[image]

Comment: I finally found the culprit: `poetrytex` does `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`, which of course interferes with `\@chapter`.

Comment: Ah perfect thanks - I couldn't identify where the problem was coming from, but that did the job excellently.